# Is rank function supported in python sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm wondering if `python` `sqlite3` library supports RANK() function.

When I execute a query via online `Sqlite` Browser it works fine, but via `python` it fails.

```
File "xyz.py", line 509, in createData
    conn.execute('SELECT RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY dateAndTime)  FROM xyz;')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried removing the ";" at the end of the query statement? I think there should not be any problem having rank() via python. have a look here https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_sqlite_in_python_tutorial.html as it might help

Comment: Sqlite got window functions in 3.25, so you have to be using that or newer.

Comment: Yes, my lib is version 3.22. Thanks for your help @Shawn

Comment: https://github.com/coleifer/pysqlite3

Answer (score 1):

It was pointed out by Shawn that my lib is too old.
Br

> Sqlite got window functions in 3.25, so you have to be using that or newer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the version of SQLite which your Python script is using supports `RANK()`.  Assuming it does not, here is a query you may use as a workaround:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t2.id < t1.id) rnk
FROM yourTable t1
ORDER BY
    dateAndTime;
```

We can use a correlated subquery to handle the rank logic.  Note that for `DENSE_RANK`, it might not be so easy to workaround.

Here is a demo showing that my logic and `RANK` behave the same way.

### Demo

Comment: How does this help if the lib does not support rank?

Comment: @user2532072 Sorry, I pasted the wrong query in the answer.  Check the updated answer or demo.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use row_number() instead:

```
row_number()
```

combined with ascending (ASC) or descending (DESC) to get a sorted ranking

```
ORDER BY DESC # or ASC
```

Also, this might be useful when working with sqlite in python
http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/

Comment: I agre that would work for my test example, but my actual case needs rank